# How to solve FindBugs DP_DO_INSIDE_DO_PRIVILEGED

Tags: java, findbugs

When reading and scanning an old codes, I saw these lines of code :

```
public static void replaceNull(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    if (fields != null)
    {
        for (Field field : fields)
        {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
            try
            {
                if (field.get(obj) == null)
                {
                    setDefaultValue(obj, field, fieldType);
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                logger. error("failed replacing null :"+ e.getMessage(),e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                logger. error("failed replacing null :"+ e.getMessage(),e);
            }

        }
    }
}

   private static void setDefaultValue(Object obj, Field field, Class<?> fieldType) throws IllegalAccessException
{
    if (fieldType == String.class)
    {
        field.set(obj, CommonConstants.BLANK);

    } else if (fieldType == Date.class)
    {
        field.set(obj, new Date());
    } else if (fieldType == Long.class)
    {
        field.setLong(obj, 0L);
    } else if (fieldType == Integer.class)
    {
        field.setInt(obj, 0);
    } else if (fieldType == BigDecimal.class)
    {
        field.set(obj, new BigDecimal("0.0"));
    }
}
```

From the flow of the program, it seems that the writer want to create a default values for all of the data member of the object if the value is null.

Upon scanning using FindBugs, the findbugs reported "DP_DO_INSIDE_DO_PRIVILEGED" with this description on setAccessible(true):

> Bad practice - Method invoked that should be only be invoked inside a doPrivileged block
>   Plugin: findbugs    Key: DP_DO_INSIDE_DO_PRIVILEGED
>   This code invokes a method that requires a security permission check. If this code will be granted security permissions, but might be invoked by code that does not have security permissions, then the invocation needs to occur inside a doPrivileged block.

My question why is this bad? And how should I solve it?

Comment: *field.setAccessible(true);* requires `suppressAccessChecks` permission.  You can "solve" the case via `AccessController.doPrivileged(...)` wrapping the entire code within a `PrivilegedAction`. Alternatively ignore this warning from FindBugs. Not all bugs/warnings are valid in any context. Also the entire function might be already wrapped but usually FindBugs won't manage to detect that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Javadocs of [`field#setAccessible(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-):

> First, if there is a security manager, its checkPermission method is called with a ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks") permission.

Without a `SecurityManager` installed, the program will run fine. However, imagine that your code is written as a shared library, and it happens to be used by some module that has setup a security manager in place. In this case, `field.setAccessible(true)` may be denied permission even though this and other operations in your code are considered as trusted code. That's why FindBugs raises this warning.

In order to guarantee that `field.setAccessible(true)` will always be granted permission regardless of the permissions of the caller code, you can wrap the statement inside a `AccessController.doPrivileged` (you'd have to make `field` final):

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the accepted answer above, Using Java 1.7+ lambda expressions, the same can be achieved with:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction) () -> {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since both the `SecurityManager` and `AccessController` were deprecated in Java 17 and remain without replacements, disabling this bug detection should be considered safe. Refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/AccessController.html) for more details.

There is also a SpotBugs issue regarding this: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1515

> Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a
> future version. This class is only useful in conjunction with the
> Security Manager, which is deprecated and subject to removal in a
> future release. Consequently, this class is also deprecated and
> subject to removal. There is no replacement for the Security Manager
> or this class.